# Preventing Cursor GameObject from going below the level in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game features a teleport that works by having a gameObject controlled by the user's mouse which moves in a radius around the player. When the player clicks the left mouse button, they are then teleported to the cursor's location and the cursor then moves to where the mouse now is accordingly.

This is the main part of the teleport feature and it works perfectly. The only problem is that the gameObject can pass through my level design which allows the player to teleport below the level and be stuck under it. This is obviously a problem and I have tried to resolve it by giving the gameObject a Rigidbody2D Component and a Box Collider, thinking that when it touches the Level's Tilemap Collider it will be unable to pass through similarly to how the player's box collider doesn't allow it to pass through the level. This however has not worked and I do not know how to continue.

I don't know if this is needed but here is my Teleport class just in case:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public float radius;
    public bool canTeleport = true;
    public Vector2 screenPosition;
    public Vector2 worldPosition;
    public bool ground_check;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 Mouse_Cord = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        Vector2 Player_Coord = Player.transform.position;

        Vector2 Player_Cursor_Distance = Mouse_Cord - Player_Coord;

        Vector2 dir = Player_Cursor_Distance.normalized;
        Vector2 cursorVector = dir * radius;

        Vector2 final_Distance = Player_Coord + cursorVector;

        transform.position = final_Distance;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canTeleport == true)
        {
            T_Port(final_Distance);
        }

        else
        {
            ground_check = Player.GetComponent<CharacterController2D>().m_Grounded;

            if (!ground_check && canTeleport == false)
            {
                canTeleport = false;
            }
            else
     

   {
            canTeleport = true;
        }
    }
}



private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    UnityEditor.Handles.DrawWireDisc(transform.parent.position, Vector3.back, radius);
}

public void T_Port(Vector2 distance2)
{
    worldPosition = distance2;

    Player.transform.position = worldPosition;

    canTeleport = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Because you dont use phyiscs to move.